# Python - Suds0.4 - SOAP body complex arguments

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

I try to connect a python client - via SUDS0.4 - to a SOAP server. 
Usually, to provide a complex argument to a SOAP function, I use a python dictionary:
Example, if the SOAP argument looks like:

```
<parameterDesignatorValuePair>
<parameterDesignator>Message</parameterDesignator>
<parameterValue>AAAABgBDAG8AdQBjAG8AdQ==</parameterValue>
</parameterDesignatorValuePair>
```

My python code looks like:

```
result = client.service.myfunction(parameterDesignatorValuePair={'parameterDesignator':val1,'parameterValue':val2})
```

Now I try to connect to a SOAP server that I haven't programed but I know how the SOAP body of my request has to look like from a existing java client: (part of interest)

```
...
<parameterDesignatorValuePairSet>
<parameterDesignatorValuePair>
<parameterDesignator>Message</parameterDesignator>
<parameterValue>AAAABgBDAG8AdQBjAG8AdQ==</parameterValue>
</parameterDesignatorValuePair>
<parameterDesignatorValuePair>
<parameterDesignator>Sender</parameterDesignator>
<parameterValue>AAAABwBSAGUAbgBhAHUAbABk</parameterValue>
</parameterDesignatorValuePair>
</parameterDesignatorValuePairSet>
...
```

So I have to pass the complex argument "parameterDesignatorValuePairSet" composed of two complex arguments which have exactly the same name "parameterDesignatorValuePair": I can't do that by using a python dictionary :-(

I tried to use list and tuple but SUDS returns me errors ...

Thank for the help

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to just do this:

```
param = client.factory.create('ns1:parameterDesignatorValuePairNamespace')
param.parameterDesignator = val1
param.parameterValue = val2

client.service.FunctionName(param)
```

Namespaces are available by printing the WSDL file after SUDS connection.